# Error in Consuming WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to consume a wcf service from a client application. The WCF services is hosted in web.
After i add the service reference to the project, all the proxy gets generated.

when I'm trying to access the proxy class methods., I'm getting the below error:

An endpoint configuration section for contract 'XService.XServicePortType' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

In app.config, i removed custom binding end points. I have just one http end point.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding> xxxxxxx </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="x" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="xServiceSoap11Binding" 
              contract="xServicePortType" 
              name="xHttpSoap11Endpoint" />
    <endpoint address="y" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="ySoap11Binding" 
              contract="yServicePortType" 
              name="yHttpSoap11Endpoint" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Fails at line:

```
XServicePortTypeClient buService = new XServicePortTypeClient();
```

The code for XServicePortType is auto generated.

```
<endpoint name="xServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint1" contract="xService.xServicePortType" bindingType="basicHttpBinding" address="http://zz:8086/RABSAPI2BUService/services/xService.xServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/" bindingConfiguration="xServiceSoap11Binding1">
  <properties>
    <property path="/address" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.Uri, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>http://zz:8086/RABSAPI2BUService/services/xService.xServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/behaviorConfiguration" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
    <property path="/binding" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>basicHttpBinding</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/bindingConfiguration" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>xServiceSoap11Binding1</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/contract" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>xService.xServicePortType</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/headers" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.AddressHeaderCollectionElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.AddressHeaderCollectionElement</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/headers/headers" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeaderCollection, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>&lt;Header /&gt;</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.IdentityElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.IdentityElement</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/userPrincipalName" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.UserPrincipalNameElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.UserPrincipalNameElement</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/userPrincipalName/value" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/servicePrincipalName" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicePrincipalNameElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicePrincipalNameElement</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/servicePrincipalName/value" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/dns" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.DnsElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.DnsElement</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/dns/value" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/rsa" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.RsaElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.RsaElement</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/rsa/value" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/certificate" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CertificateElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CertificateElement</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/certificate/encodedValue" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/certificateReference" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CertificateReferenceElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CertificateReferenceElement</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/certificateReference/storeName" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>My</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/certificateReference/storeLocation" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>LocalMachine</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/certificateReference/x509FindType" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>FindBySubjectDistinguishedName</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/certificateReference/findValue" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
    <property path="/identity/certificateReference/isChainIncluded" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>False</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/name" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue>xServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint1</serializedValue>
    </property>
    <property path="/kind" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
    <property path="/endpointConfiguration" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <serializedValue />
    </property>
  </properties>
</endpoint>
```

---

@Mike C: The code for XServicePortType is auto generated.

```
 <endpoint name="xServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint1" contract="xService.xServicePortType" bindingType="basicHttpBinding" address="http://zz:8086/RABSAPI2BUService/services/xService.xServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/" bindingConfiguration="xServiceSoap11Binding1">
      <properties>
        <property path="/address" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.Uri, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>http://zz:8086/RABSAPI2BUService/services/xService.xServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/behaviorConfiguration" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
        <property path="/binding" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>basicHttpBinding</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/bindingConfiguration" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>xServiceSoap11Binding1</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/contract" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>xService.xServicePortType</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/headers" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.AddressHeaderCollectionElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.AddressHeaderCollectionElement</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/headers/headers" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeaderCollection, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>&lt;Header /&gt;</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.IdentityElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.IdentityElement</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/userPrincipalName" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.UserPrincipalNameElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.UserPrincipalNameElement</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/userPrincipalName/value" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/servicePrincipalName" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicePrincipalNameElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServicePrincipalNameElement</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/servicePrincipalName/value" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/dns" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.DnsElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.DnsElement</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/dns/value" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/rsa" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.RsaElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.RsaElement</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/rsa/value" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/certificate" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CertificateElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CertificateElement</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/certificate/encodedValue" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/certificateReference" isComplexType="true" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CertificateReferenceElement, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>System.ServiceModel.Configuration.CertificateReferenceElement</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/certificateReference/storeName" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>My</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/certificateReference/storeLocation" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>LocalMachine</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/certificateReference/x509FindType" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>FindBySubjectDistinguishedName</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/certificateReference/findValue" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
        <property path="/identity/certificateReference/isChainIncluded" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>False</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/name" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="true" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue>xServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint1</serializedValue>
        </property>
        <property path="/kind" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
        <property path="/endpointConfiguration" isComplexType="false" isExplicitlyDefined="false" clrType="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <serializedValue />
        </property>
      </properties>
    </endpoint>
```

Comment: can you show your config and your client code?

Comment: Appconfig:
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
   xxxxxxx
 </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
 <client>
      <endpoint address="x"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xServiceSoap11Binding"
          contract="xServicePortType" name="xHttpSoap11Endpoint" />
      <endpoint address="y"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ySoap11Binding"
          contract="yServicePortType" name="yHttpSoap11Endpoint" />
      </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

Code:

 XServicePortTypeClient buService = new XServicePortTypeClient();

Comment: buService.search(RequestObject);

while initialzing a variable of type "xServicePortTypeClient buService = new xServicePortTypeClient();", im getting the above mentioned error!

Comment: Does your code create an endpoint programatically?

Comment: Also please edit your question and post the code for `XServicePortType`, which I assume is implemented as a `ServiceContract`.

Comment: @hugh : Yes it automatically creates the end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An endpoint configuration section for contract
>   'XService.XServicePortType' could not be loaded because more than one
>   endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate
>   the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

Include the assembly name with your contract in the bindings.  Also, XML is case sensitive so **xServicePortType** is not the same as **XServicePortType**.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding> xxxxxxx </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="x" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="xServiceSoap11Binding" 
              contract="XService.XServicePortType" 
              name="xHttpSoap11Endpoint" />
    <endpoint address="y" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="ySoap11Binding" 
              contract="YService.YServicePortType" 
              name="yHttpSoap11Endpoint" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Mike pl. check the auto generated code for XServicePortType below